# Is the following curve a circle?

Tags: geometry

Let $\gamma(\theta)=(\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos\theta,\sin(\theta+\alpha)\sin\theta),\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Is $\gamma(\theta)$ a circle? What is the radius of it?

Comment: Hint http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

Comment: Plot it (for some suitably chosen values of $\alpha$, such as $0$ and $\pi/2$). Does is look like a circle? If so, what does its center and radius appear to be? If you write down the naive parameterization of a circle with that center and radius, can you prove that it equals your $\gamma$?

Comment: Pedantic note: $\gamma$ might or might not be (the equation of) a circle (here, it is) but $\gamma(\theta)$ is a point in the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recall two trigonometric identities:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin\gamma\cos\delta & = \frac{\sin(\gamma+\delta)+\sin(\gamma-\delta)}{2} \\  \\
\sin\gamma\sin\delta & = \frac{\cos(\gamma-\delta)-\cos(\gamma+\delta)}{2}
\end{align}
$$
So put $\theta+\alpha$ in the role of $\gamma$ and $\theta$ in the role of $\delta$.  Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\theta+\alpha)\cos\theta & = \frac{\sin\alpha+\sin(2\theta+\alpha)}{2} \\  \\
\sin(\theta+\alpha)\sin\theta & = \frac{\cos\alpha-\cos(2\theta+\alpha)}{2}
\end{align}
$$
As $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, this point goes **twice** around a circle centered at $(\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)/2$, with radius $1/2$ (and diameter $1$).

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, the equation of this curve is 
$$
r=\sin(\theta+\alpha)=\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\alpha).
$$ 
One sees that $r^2=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)+r\cos(\theta)\sin(\alpha)=y\cos(\alpha)+x\sin(\alpha)$, hence
$$
x^2+y^2-x\sin(\alpha)-y\cos(\alpha)=0.
$$
This is indeed the equation of a circle. Let me indicate its radius is $
\frac12$ and leave you the joy to find its center.